# complete dependencies to resolve the import of org.apache.commons.io

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, apache-poi, pom.xml

At the moment I have a non-maven project with external libraries in intelliJ. Now I wanted to import `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`. But it cannot be resolved. I read some questions and answers on stackoverflow. Since I have no `pom.xml` file that can be completed, is there another approach to import the library?

Comment: Yes, you need to download library that interest you. And then add it to your classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download jars which interest you from [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi). 
And add it to your classpath [check this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html)